# UITableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths out of order

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I currently have a UISegmentedControl set to add/remove table view cells when its value changes. Removing cells works perfectly, however when I insert cells they're in reverse order every other time.

```
NSArray *addindexes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0], [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0], [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:0], nil];
NSArray *removeindexes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0], [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0], [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:0], nil];
[self.tableView beginUpdates];

switch (switchType.selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0:
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:addindexes withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        break;
    case 1:
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:removeindexes withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

        break;
    default:
        break;
}

[self.tableView endUpdates];}
```

For example, every other time I add/remove cells they're in reverse order. (4, 3, 2 instead of 2, 3, 4) 
1) Remove cells- add cells- correct order 
2) Remove cells- add cells- incorrect order 
3) Remove cells- add cells- correct order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each cell created a UITextField. To prevent this from being drawn multiple times I used

```
if (!someTextField)
```

This caused the cell not to be updated since the text field was already drawn. To solve the issue I simply added `[someTextField removeFromSuperview]` as the row was being deleted.

Comment: Hi,I am facing this issue now, can you explained more details?

Answer (score 1):

All that your code sample shows is the indexes.  The display order of the cells is determined by your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: Yes, I realize this but there isn't a reason why this would cause the order of the cells to change. Unless I'm missing something huge.

I have tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath set up with switch(indexPath.row). The problem is the display order changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no one else has seen this behavior. It is easily observed with a table view of toggle switches controlled by a master switch. Take for example this textual representation of a table view with 4 sections. On initial load, everything is as expected:

> Section 0
>
> - Row 0 / Toggle tag is 0 (permanent master switch, inserts/removes sections 1-3)
>
> Section 1
>
> - Row 0 / Toggle tag is **1**
> - Row 1 / Toggle tag is **2**
>
> Section 2
>
> - Row 0 / Toggle tag is **3**
> - Row 1 / Toggle tag is **4**
>
> Section 3
>
> - Row 0 / Toggle tag is **5**

After switching the master toggle OFF to remove sections 1-3, then back ON to insert sections 1-3, the toggle tags are in reverse order:

> Section 0
>
> - Row 0 / Toggle tag is 0 (permanent master switch, inserts/removes sections 1-3)
>
> Section 1
>
> - Row 0 / Toggle tag is **5**
> - Row 1 / Toggle tag is **4**
>
> Section 2
>
> - Row 0 / Toggle tag is **3**
> - Row 1 / Toggle tag is **2**
>
> Section 3
>
> - Row 0 / Toggle tag is **1**

The way I worked around it was by ditching `toggle.tag = myRowIteratorVariable` inside the `if( cell == nil )` block. Instead, after that block, I set toggle.tag to a row ID that I predefine in my data:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UISwitch *toggle = nil;
    ...
    if( cell == nil )
    {
        ...
        toggle = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
        //toggle.tag = myRowIteratorVariable;
        ...
    }

    NSDictionary *section = [myTableViewSectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *rowIds = [section objectForKey:@"rowIds"];
    int rowId = [[rowIds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue];
    toggle.tag = rowId;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that in my case that reuse cell value will lead this issue,I solve it by assign new value before return cell